Is this a correct way to prove that p lacks of that which its composed of (a,b) using fuzzy logic?
P: composed of parts.
a,b: the parts that p is composed of.
x: is an attribute of p.
y=μ_a(x)+μ_b(x)=μ_P(x)
P=a+b
x∈P
1- x ∈ a = μ_a(x)=1
But p=a+b so μ_p(x)=y
:μ_p(x)≥  y but y>1 so μ_p(x)>1
2- x ∈ b = μ_b(x) =1
But p=a+b so μ_p(x)=y
:μ_p(x)≥  y but y>1 so μ_p(x)>1
3- x ∈ a ,b = μ_a(x)=1 and μ_b(x)=1
So y=2
:. x can't exist in x,b just in p
we conclude that element X belongs to p only, so it cannot obtain x without composition, so it lacks a and b.
Is this a correct way to prove that, that which is composed of parts (a,b) lacks those parts...through fuzzy logic using membership function.
